# Seeing the same access token between apps

Tags: c#, reactjs, identityserver4

I have a local instance of identity server (IS). I have a container app and a child app and the container app is configured with identity server. The child app is launched from the container app (url link).

When I launch the container app, I can log into IS as expected. Then when I launch the child app (via the link), I see the same id token and access token being used on the child app.

I suppose this is expected.

However, if I configure the child app with IS, I was expecting a new access token for the child app but instead, I am seeing the same access token as the container app.

Is this correct behavior or should new access token be given for the child app?

On my child app I have a controller with the following:

```
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");

            // Now you can use them. For more info on when and how to use the 
            // access_token and id_token, see https://auth0.com/docs/tokens
        }
```

The controller has the [Authorize] attribute.

Idsrv4 config:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "react_main_container_app_implicit",
                ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = new []
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "singlespa_access",
                    "employee_info"
                },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = new [] { "http://localhost:63580/signin-oidc" }, //mw knows how to handle this.
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new []{"http://localhost:63580/signout-callback-oidc"}
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "react-child_app_implicit",
                ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                // RequireConsent =  true,
                AllowedScopes = new []
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "singlespa_access"
                },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = new [] { "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" }, //mw knows how to handle this.
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new []{"http://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc"}
            }
```

and

```
            services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(true)
            .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources()) // these are now called scopes. API allowed to use auth server.
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfiguration.IdentityResources())
            .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users());
```

Comment: How did you determine that it is the same access token?

Comment: I'm assuming the child app is using the same cookie as its parent?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius: see edited question. Thanks.

Comment: @mackie. In fact if I just launch the child app first and then launch the container app in another chrome window I see the access token of the child passed to the container app. In the child app, I am required to login to IS but not in the container app.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, then the behaviour you are describing is expected and is due to single sign on effect because when you login to Identity Server 4 with user credentials, it leaves the cookie and then once your another client redirects to the same identity provider, the cookie authentication scheme kicks in and automatically logs the user in and issues the token without requiring credential input.

You should, however, still go through consent screen if your client is configured with `RequireConsent = true` and you are using different `client_id` for your applications.

Comment: Thank you @Vidmantas. Just to confirm when you say 'issue the token', you mean the same token? I read somewhere a new token is given. If only one access token is used, can I not have both apps configured in IS with different scopes? Or would the main container app contain the scopes of the child app as well?

Comment: @Videopinme should be different token, but how do you constitute different token. Your apps should not have any scopes of their own to be honest, they should be allowed some scopes, whether those are different or not, it doesn't matter if they are different clients.

Comment: So the reason I say they are not different is because when I take the access tokens and decode them they have the same information. The client id is the same in both tokens. I was expecting the client id of the child token to be different.

Comment: You need to share your idsrv4 configurations or else I’m lost a bit in trying to help you

Comment: Configuration added.

Comment: Just to recap, I am stilling seeing the same issue where the child app has the same access token as the container. In fact, if I first log in with the child app, then the container app has the same token. So it looks like the IS configuration for the second app is not being used if the first app has already authenticated.